# How to migrate spring-mvc application in jasypt 1.9.x with spring security 4.0 + spring 4.1 and hibernate 4.x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Currently my application is in jasypt 1.9.0 and spring security 3.1.0 and spring 3.1.2 but I want to migrate it in jasypt 1.9.2 and spring securiyt 4.0.0 and spring  4.1.6.

I am unable to login in application after migration. j_spring_security_check always call access-denied-handler all time.

**snapshot of pom.xml is following**

```
<properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.springsecurity-version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springsecurity-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.8.6</org.aspectj-version>
        <jayspt-version>1.9.2</jayspt-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.4</org.slf4j-version>
        <logback.version>1.0.6</logback.version>
        <springframework-webflow-version>2.4.0.RELEASE</springframework-webflow-version>
    </properties>
```

**login.jsp :**

```
                <form name="f" action="<c:url value='login'/>"
                    method="post">
                    <fieldset id="user-details">
                        <label for="username">Username</label> <input type="text"
                            name="username" /> <label for="password">Password</label> <input
                            type="password" name="password" /> <input type="submit"
                            value="Sign In"  id="submit_first" name="submit_first"
                            class="submit" /> 

                            <input type="button" id="forgot" value="Forgot Password" onclick="callForgotPassword();" class="forgotpwd" />
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

**security.xml : (after reverting changes)**

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/css/*.css"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/Wave2LogoLogin.png"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/utlLogoHeader.png"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/*"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/validate"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/validateDate"
            access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" /> 
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/showNcprCheckPoint"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/makeNcprCheckPoint"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/chargingUrls"
            access="isAuthenticated()" />

        <security:access-denied-handler
            error-page="/WEB-INF/views/superadmin/superadminpanel.jsp" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successfulLoginService"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="failedLoginService" />
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1" expired-url="/" />
        </security:session-management>
```

Please help.

Comment: Because it now is `/login` instead of `/j_spring_security_check`.

Comment: As described here https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2783

Comment: make sure access is permitted to that URL.

Comment: @M.Deinum stil not working and still call security:access-denied-handler.

Comment: post your configuration and login page...

Comment: @M.Deinum i have send the all files after reverting it.

Comment: Your config is flawed... The `intercept-url` are all consulted in the order they are defined in. Your `/**` should always be last! basically everything beyond that is useless. You should permit all access to `/login` else it will fail. Also I would say that `<c:url value="login`" />~ must contain a `/` as now it is relative to the current URL which might not match `/login` ...

Comment: @M.Deinum I do all changes but still have the same problem. change login to /login, give permission to login url and /** in last. :(

Comment: You must have something else, maybe encryption decryption of passwords, your credentials aren't correct or you are redirected to a page you don't have access to.

Comment: Is it possible to use jasypt 1.9.2 with spring 4.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally find the solution. Just changes access in JSP file and also same changes to spring-security.xml, I am able to see the landing page.

Thanks to M.Deinum